# Why is the $max-function of the aggregate framework slower than iterating a cursor?

Tags: java, mongodb

I got a dataset of about 300.000 entries. For storing that data I'm using the current version of mongodb 2.2.3. My question is how to improve the performance of searching by using the aggregation framework?

This is an example of my stored data:

```
{
    "_id":"654311649875645643131564",
    "@type":"K",
    "dataSourceA":{
        "name": "abc",
        "price": 12.99
    },
    "dataSourceB":{
        "name": "xyz"
    }
}
```

Before I switched to the newer version of mongodb I handled searching of e.g. the max value without the aggregation framework like this:

```
searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("dataSourceA.price", -1);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find().sort(searchQuery).limit(1);
```

This operation takes about `0.921 secs`

Now I tried the aggregation Framework to achieve the same result but would like to find the max price faster. This is my approach:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("@type", "K"));
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("dataSourceA.price", 1);          
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 1);
groupFields.put("max", new BasicDBObject("$max", "$dataSourceA.price"));

DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

Iterable<DBObject> results = 
    collection.aggregate(match, project, group).results();
```

But this operation needs about `4.837 secs` to find the max price. So what could be improved in my query? I thought a database like this should be faster than iterating a cursor in java, correct me when I'm wrong.

Comment: how does it compare to exactly the same operation with find?  In the first case you are not filtering the results at all. if match had a cursor to use, aggregation framework would take advantage of it - in fact, if you match and the add a sort before the group, if they are supported with a cursor it should speed things up significantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons for this.

First, for your cursor example, you are just running a query sorting all root documents on a subdocument field, most likely indexed. This will be faster no matter how you look at it.

Second `$max` is actually a `$group` operator which means that it is a in-memory operation on all the documents that fit into your query set (all 300,000 of them), so MongoDB is calculating the max of the multi-value field per document, grouped on `_id`, for all documents in the result set.

As a result of how `$max` works you instantly lose the immediate sorting ability you would get from the indexed cursor.

Not only that but you are also projecting halfway through the aggregation making MongoDB forcefully split up your documents further.

So no, it should not be faster than iterating a sorted indexed cursor.